# Plot multiple lines with different colors

Tags: r, dataframe, line

I am trying to create a plot i has multiple lines (data series). Each of these lines is a category and I want it to have a unique color.

How do I make each of these to lines have a unique color ?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

My data frame structure:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("04:00", 
"04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", 
"05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", 
"06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", 
"07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", 
"08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", 
"10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", 
"11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", 
"12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", 
"13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", 
"14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", 
"15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", 
"17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", 
"18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", "19:00", "19:10", 
"19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", 
"20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", 
"21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", 
"22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50", 
"00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", 
"01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", 
"02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", 
"03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), class = "factor"), WhereHome = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1), WhereWork = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Witch = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OtherAct = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How to improve this plot?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to plot? I'll suggest you to explore the function `matplot`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet for 2 lines.

**Code**

```
# Create plot
plot(data$Var1, data$WhereWork,
      main="Overlaying Graphs",
      ylab="",
      type="l",
      col="blue")

# Add other lines
lines(data$Var1,data$WhereHome, col="red")
lines(...)

# Add legend to the lines
legend("topleft",
        c("A","B"),
        fill=c("blue","red")
 )
```

**Plot**
[image: Sample plot]

Comment: If there are many columns, it's difficult to do this. That's why I suggested `matplot` in the comment section.